# How to take a vector of points and grab only 'y' of those points

Tags: c++, vector

Unfortunately my math abilities and objective-c/c/c++ isn't developed enough to understand how to do this.

I have a vector set up like this:
 [2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6] <-- i think thats how vectors are set up correct?

This is sort of what i think it should be set up:

```
vector<CGPoint>::iterator i;
    vector<CGPoint>* dp = xGraph.GraphPoints;
    for(i = dp->begin(); i != dp->end(); ++i){
        /* grab y points only code here*/
    }
```

Now I want to write some kind of `for` statement that takes `xGraph.GraphPoints` and only grabs the y coords.
and... i guess puts it into another vector of only y coords, which looks like [2,3,4,5,6] after the code is finished

Can someone help me out here?

Cheers

Comment: If you have a vector<CGPoint>, then you're using C++, not Objective-C or C. Are you sure you're not using C++?

Comment: The code you show is not C. Do you want to translate it?

Comment: Your correct. I am building an ipad application, using all 3. Fixed it

Comment: j++; if ( !(j%2) ) y.push( dp[i] );

Comment: @JohnRiselvato I have removed the [Objective-C] and [C] tags. Whether you use it in other parts of your application does not really affect that this particular question is C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my interpretation of your question is that you have a vector that contains `CGPoint` objects and you want to extract only the `y` coordinate from all of the points. In that case you want something like (using C++11 lambdas):

```
std::vector<CGFloat> ycoord;
std::transform( dp->begin(), dp->end(), std::back_inserter( ycoord ), 
                []( CGPoint const & p ){ return p.y; } );
```

If the compiler does not support lambdas, you can write a simple function to perform the extraction:

```
CGFloat extractY( CGPoint const & p ) {
   return p.y;
}
std::transform( dp->begin(), dp->end(), std::back_inserter( ycoord ), 
                &extractY );
```

Or functor:

```
struct extractYfunctor {
   CGFloat operator()( CGPoint const & p ) const {
      return p.y;
   }
};
std::transform( dp->begin(), dp->end(), std::back_inserter( ycoord ), 
                extractYfuctor() );
```

If you can use the boost libraries:

```
std::transform( dp->begin(), dp->end(), std::back_inserter( ycoord ),
                boost::bind( &CGPoint::y, _1 ) );
```

Or with a plain loop:

```
for ( std::vector< CGPoint >::const_iterator it = dp->begin(); it != dp->end(); ++it ) {
   ycoord.push_back( it->y );
}
```

Comment: Extract only the y coords into another vector. but other then that your correct on the interpretation. let me look over your code some more.

Comment: can you explain the it->y in the plain loop? oh never mind push_back right. i got it

Answer (score 2):

Your vector is not set up like [2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]. It's set up like this:  [(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)]. That is, it's a list of *pairs* of numbers, not just a list of numbers. To get the `y` component of each element in the vector, you can write a loop like this:

```
vector<CGPoint>* dp = xGraph.GraphPoints;
for(i = dp->begin(); i != dp->end(); ++i){
    /* grab y points only code here*/
    CGFloat current_y = i->y;
}
```

Comment: this this make current_y a vector? I'll go read about CGFloat since i don't understand that line.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<CGPoint>::iterator i;
vector<CGPoint>* dp = xGraph.GraphPoints;
vector<CGFloat> dp = yPoints;
for(i = dp->begin(); i != dp->end(); ++i){
    yPoints.push_back(i->y);
}
```

vectors are indeed laid out like that in memory, but not logically.  Don't overthink things.  It's still a vector of `CGFloat` objects.

Comment: what is yPoints going to be in my header?

Comment: I dunno what you're doing.  `puts it into another vector of only y coords...`  It sounds like a temporary variable, which does not belong in the header.   It should be local to a function.

Comment: Ah i see. Like I said in the first line, my programming skills are not very advance.